# Loop through several lines until a condition is reached

Tags: powershell, keepass

I have a command to retrieve info from a keepass database using the kpscript.
This command may retrieve 1 line, multiple line on none, but, in the end, it always returns this output:

`OK: Operation completed successfully.`

What is the best way to handle each line individually with PowerShell and exit the loop if StartsWith("OK:"):
Example:

```
KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH

Administrator
OK: Operation completed successfully.
```

Following approaches I have tried unsuccessfully

```
$UNAME = KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH 
IF(! $UNAME){ 
    write-host "UNAME1=$UNAME" 
    write-host "ERROR UNAME" -foreground "red" 
    exit 
}
```

and

```
while (! $UNAME) { KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH }
```

Also unsuccessful

```
    $UNAME=KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH
    write-host "UNAME=$UNAME"
```

The result:

```
    UNAME=Administrator OK: Operation completed successfully.
```

The point is to have:
        UNAME=administrator
        UNAME=OK: Operation completed successfully.
So every line can be treated individualy

Maybe this be accomplished with an array?

Also unsuccessful

```
    $UNAME=@(KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH)
    write-host "UNAME=$UNAME"
```

Output is the same:

```
    UNAME=Administrator OK: Operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You already have the jist of an idea. Are you familiar with loops on PowerShell and the pipeline?

Comment: I have in fact tried many things: while, for, foreach, but I can't seen to get the result I want, that's why I'm asking for help. What I need in the end is to treat each line individually depending on the data

Comment: That is awesome. I appreciate your effort. Can you show it here?

Comment: since I made so many test and none of them were working, i don't have the tests anymore, sorry ...

Comment: Of all the test you cant recreate just one of them? This reads like a code writing request which is not what SO is for. If you show a smiddgen of effort it can go a long way here.

Comment: I'll recreate them again, no problem :)

Comment: First I tried with no loop like this $UNAME=KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH
 IF (! $UNAME) {
  write-host "UNAME1=$UNAME"
  write-host "ERROR UNAME" -foreground "red"
  exit
 } but the variable got both lines in it

Comment: Then I tryed with while like this while (! $UNAME) {
  KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH
 } but I got an infinite loop

Comment: I also tried the foreach, but I don't think that's the right way

Comment: Do you want to display the lines until ok is reached?

Comment: My first post shows exactly the output for a single command. Would you like other kind of example?

Comment: `if($UNAME -match "OK: Operation completed successfully"){"found"}`?

Comment: I tried if($UNAME.StartsWith("OK:")) {"found"} but $UNAME gets the value and the ok like, all together. I need to separate the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
#Sample of kpscript output
#$output = "Administrator","OK: Operation completed successfully.","Should have stopped already"

$output = KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName $SEARCH

foreach ($line in $output) {
    $UNAME = $line
    Write-Host "UNAME=$UNAME"
    if($line.StartsWith("OK:")) { break }
}
```

Ouptut (using the sample-output):

```
UNAME=Administrator
UNAME=OK: Operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: I used a foreach-loop here because I seem to remember that `break` didn't stop the pipeline in `Foreach-Object` (you needed to throw a `PipelineStoppedException`), but in Win10 using both PS5.0 and PS2.0 it works like it should with `1..10 | Foreach-object { if ($_ -eq 5) { break }; $_ }`? Anyone know why?

Comment: Thank you Frode, that is what I want in fact, but I'm getting an error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At Z:\CSP\deploys\aplicacional\teste.ps1:26 char:24
+     if($line.StartsWith <<<< ("OK:")) { break }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Start
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull. Seams like nothing is getting to the $line variable

Comment: check `$output` does it contain anything?

Comment: My bad, it works, thank you. If you can help me with another question, in case UNAME can have several values, I wanted to put them all in an array. How can I do this?

Comment: `$uname = @()` outside the loop and `$uname += $line` inside

Comment: I'm opening a new question for this because it's different from the original one

Answer (score 0):

old topic but maybe it helps someone, this is how i solved it
Use the paramters -FailIfNoEntry -FailIfNotExists this will give you a line starting with E: *** message when the field is empty or the entry is not found

$information will contain an array with the usefull information

```
$RawEntiries = & $kpscript -c:GetEntryString $PathKeepass -pw:$pscred.GetNetworkCredential().password -Field:$Field -ref-Title:"$title" -FailIfNoEntry -FailIfNotExists

If ($RawEntiries -notlike "E:*")
{
    $information = $RawEntiries[0..($RawEntiries.IndexOf("OK: Operation completed successfully.")-1)]
    $Information
}
```